# Integration Methods of Sugar CRM

Tags: php, web-services, soap, sugarcrm

I am going to develop a complex web application related to affiliates. I want to integrate `sugarCRM` as the `CRM` module of my affiliate application. I have some misunderstandings related to integration methods. From [FAQs](http://developers.sugarcrm.com/overview.php#q30) at Sugar CRM website, It is stated that there are two ways to integrate one is `Webservice API` and second is `Module Builder`.

**Now** let me first tell you about my understanding. If you have a standalone application running on your server and you want to integrate the CRM then you have to choose `Web Services API` for it. But if you have installed CRM on your server and not having any other standalone application then you can use `Module Builder` Method. It is just like you like you have installed any CMS and creates modules to extend the functionality.

**Am I rite?**

**OR** I am having wrong understanding about CRM integration? For standalone application we need to use only `Web Services API` in which we will use data using web services and show in our system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module Builder allows you to easily add new functionality to SugarCRM though an easy to use GUI.  If you want to track company Desks, Widgets, Recordings, Headaches,....anything, you would use  Module Builder to add your specific needs to SugarCRM.  You can even relate these new module items to the core modules such as contacts, accounts, etc.

Web Services API is a way to access SugarCRM data and functionality from non-SugarCRM code.  Web Services API can be used to Create, Read, Update, and Modify existing SugarCRM records through API calls.  You can use SOAP or REST to communicate with SugarCRM.  This includes accessing any newly created custom modules you built using Module Builder.  With Web Services API, you could access how many resources, Widgets, Recordings, or Headaches from another internal or external application.

Comment: So If I am having my standalone application running and want to integrate the CRM, then the only way to do is by using Web Services API?

Comment: Not necessarily. It all depends on your requirements. You could initiate your integration from within Sugar instead. For example, you could use a logic hook that detects when a new account is created. In that hook you could have it push the new account to your standalone application.

Answer (score 2):

Web Service API is almost always the correct way, if you need to integrate with SugarCRM from an external application. This method is great for small-medium amounts of data and if you need your application to be in almost sync with sugarCRM.

Other methods exists which are better suited for larger amount of data and if "realtime" sync is not needed. However, they are usually more complex and require more development and understanding of SugarCRM.
It is e.g. possible to create a PHP batch script on the SugarCRM server, which interfaces with SugarCRM API and exports/imports the given information from/to another system.

Answer (score 0):

Apart that the situation you describe is the reason why webservices exist, the ones provided by SugarCRM are extremelly flexible and allow you to access each and every feature, not only the ones provided by default, but also the ones you might develop and/or install.

Concluding, if what you really need is to perform an integration between your application and SugarCRM, you don't need to learn how to work with SugarCRM (from a developers perspective), you only need to know how to work with webservices, Soap or Rest.